# C# Prevent application from exiting when clicking quit from UnhandledException window

Tags: c#, winforms, unhandled-exception

I work on a very large C# application.  One too large to now go and catch all the possible unhandled exceptions.

The application also has an "Are you sure you want to quit?" message pop up in the app's FormClosing event.

When unhandled exceptions are run into, sometimes the users click on the quit button.  I believe this calls Application.Exit() or some form.  This also triggers the FormClosing event and the pop up window.

[image: Sample Unhandled exception dialog box]

At this point it does not matter whether you click yes or no on the pop up.  The application will quit after an answer is received because of the Application.Exit().

Is there anyway to prevent the Application.Exit() from being called?

Comment: Handle the `UnhandledException` event so you can replace the dialog entirely.

Comment: What is your code? How can we suggest you an answer without knowing your coding style!

Comment: How did you manage to create a large application while omitting even basic error handling?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to prevent the App from termination, you need to handle the exception. It is reasonable to have a try..catch in every place that might throw an exception (there should not be many). However, there is a global event for that.

If the exception in the **Main Thread** is not handled and propagates to the AppDomain Unhandled Exception, then the app is not in a valid state and it have to [terminate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965(v=vs.110).aspx). You last hope at this stage is to log exception information and try to save what can be saved before the application is terminated for good.

You need to subscribe to this event in order to log unhandled exceptions and show a user-friendly error:

```
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}

private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // we can log info from e.ExceptionObject and check e.IsTerminating
}
```

> In the .NET Framework versions 1.0 and 1.1, an unhandled exception
>   that occurs in a thread other than the main application thread is
>   caught by the runtime and therefore does not cause the application to
>   terminate. Thus, it is possible for the UnhandledException event to be
>   raised without the application terminating. Starting with the .NET
>   Framework version 2.0, this backstop for unhandled exceptions in child
>   threads was removed, because the cumulative effect of such silent
>   failures included performance degradation, corrupted data, and
>   lockups, all of which were difficult to debug. For more information,
>   including a list of cases in which the runtime does not terminate, see
>   [Exceptions in Managed Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

You may also need to handle:

```
Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
```